# 3 phase stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

What is the difference between normal stepper motor (bipolar/unipolar) and 3 phase stepper motor?
I have found most of CNC cutting machine using 3 phase stepper motor. Is there any special reason for that?

Comment: Provide links to examples please.

Comment: I haven't links for any wiring diagram or block diagram of CNC cutting machine. This is a driver of a 3 phase stepper driver on my working factory.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gkdy55iPcJN-Xm1LE18WnMPfCC0GA4tw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How about a photo of your 3-phase stepper motor?

Comment: Who manufactured the 3-phase stepper motor?